# Write an \unpar macro

Tags: macros, plain-tex

I would like to write an `\unpar` macro which removes last `\par`.
For example, the TeX code

```
 This is a \par \unpar paragraph
```

should be equivalent to

```
 This is a paragraph
```

(Note that by equivalent I mean not that it has to produce exactly the last token list:  I mean that it should have the same output as the one I will obtain using the last token list.)

A solution could be to redefine `\par` in the following way:

```
\let\oldpar\par
\def\unpar{}
\long\def\par#1{\ifx#1\unpar\else\oldpar#1\fi}
```

But this does not work if `\bye` is preceeded by a `\par` (I don't know why).  Furthermore, a redefinition of `\par` could possibly break some macro package.  So, I was wondering: Is there a way to define `\unpar` without modifying `\par`?

And what about an `\Unpar` macro which removes not just a single `\par` but all `\par`s preceeding it?

Comment: `\long\def\par#1{\ifx#1\unpar\else\csname @firstofone\expandafter\endcsname\fi{\oldpar#1}}` would work, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You can't undo a `\par` (when the command has its primitive meaning). Can you please show a typical use case for your `\unpar` command?

Comment: @egreg. For example in an `\enddemo` macro which ends a demonstration previously started by a `\demo`.  If I define `\def\enddemo{\quad\hbox{\bf QED}\medskip}` then, if I leave a blank line before putting an `\enddemo` I get the word QED on a different paragraph.  With an `\Unpar` I would define `\def\enddemo{\Unpar\quad\hbox{\bf QED}\medskip}`.
Maybe the same effect could be achieved by detecting the lenght of the last line of the demonstration and so putting the QED in the right place. But I don't know how.

Comment: I see no way, unless you redefine `\par` to look for `\enddemo`

Comment: @User but what if "the last line" has already been shipped out on the previous page? In general you need to set things up in advance, with `\demo` to  redefine `\par` not to do a real `\endgraf` until it has looked ahead, or perhaps set the whole thing in a vbox, then unbox it `\lastskip any vertical skip add your end marker then `\unvbox` the contents on to the main list for the page.

Comment: @User -- it's simply better to avoid a blank line before `\enddemo`.  if you want a visual gap in the input, put a `%` at the beginning of the otherwise empty line.

Comment: @barbara beaton. It's not the case I want to insert a blank line before an `\enddemo` for visual effect;  I only wanted to "protect" the macro from an accidentally inserted blank line.  Thank's for the suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not possible.

TeX sees `\par`.

At this point the current horizontal list is split into a vertical list of horizontal boxes, hyphenation is applied if necessary, discardable glue is discarded and left and right glue is added. Then the output routine is invoked, which may output one or more pages, possibly taking stored inserts and footnotes, and adding them to the page, then control is returned to the input stream, in vertical mode.

It would be hard to define `\unpar` to undo all this.

Comment: But would redefine `\par` be *that* impossible? Of course you can't undo, but TeX inserts the token `\par` automatically when a blank line appears, but it doesn't need to be the primitive `\par` (or am I mistaken?).

Comment: @Manuel macros redefine `\par` _all the time_ that's why plain has `\endgraf` and latex has `\@@par` to save the original definition while `\par` is redefined. But the question was whether you could avoid that.

Comment: @Manuel In `l3galley` we set things up such that the 'real' `\par` is not inserted until we are sure there's been no look-ahead for more-or-less exactly the reason David gives: you can't remove a 'real' `\par`.

Answer (score 10):

You can try something like this:

```
\def\par{\futurelet\next\dopar}
\def\dopar{\let\doparA=\endgraf
           \ifx\next\par \let\doparA\relax \fi
           \ifx\next\unpar \let\doparA\relax \fi
           \doparA}
\def\unpar{\donothing{unpar}} % any special macro with empty output
\def\donothing#1{}


This is paragraph.

Note more empty lines here:



\unpar
The paragraph is not finished.

\bye
```

Of course, you must redefine `\par`. There is no another possibility (it was explained by David Carlisle).

Your mistake was: you tried to scan next token by `#1` (macro parameter), not by `\futurelet`, wich is much more robust. The `\outer` defined macros (like `\bye`) cannot be loaded to `#1` but they can be tested using `\futurelet`. If the next token is `{` then `#1` scanning does much more work than you need to do. But `\futurelet` keeps the `{` without any changing.

Comment: Thank you!  But why `\def\unpar
{\donothing{unpar}}
\def\donothing#1{}` instead of a simpler `\def\unpar{}`?

Comment: @User because `\unpar` is equivalent to `\empty` after `\def\unpar{}`. And then `\par \empty` has the same behaviour as `\par \unpar`. This is not what you need.

Comment: @User For your application: You cannot include `\unpar` into `\enddemo` macro body because `\futurelet` does not look inside the expanded next token. Better is to add the test `\ifx\next\enddemo \let\doparA\relax\fi` to the `\dopar` definition. Then you need not the trick with `\donothing` because `\unpar` will never used by user (nor @User).

Comment: Yes, I already figured that out and comed to a solution similar to this even before you answered my question.  Anyway, your answers are always welcome: There's always something to learn from you :)